# What's the fastest way to search through a MySQL database containing billions of records?

Tags: mysql, database

I've been looking for a very fast and efficient way to search a database of an enormous size without using anything other than PHP and Mysql. What would be some options I could use?

Comment: a `select` query is the sine-non-quoa of searching a database...

Comment: Do you have a real, present use-case for this, or is it a theoretical question? If you have a database but it isn't nearly this size yet, you may be optimising too early.

Comment: I actually have this size and its growing every second by the millions.

Comment: Well, the ultimate answer is that you would need to create a database system that was faster than MySQL, isn't it? I suppose that would work if you were a good programmer. Are you asking us to give you a design for a faster database system?

Comment: The question is what kinds of queries you want. All databases are based on the queries, not the available data. If you're not going to query on or present a piece of data, then don't store it. So, until you can give examples of the types of queries you want, it's basically impossible to suggest a strategy to do them efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

The exact same way you would do it if you had 100's of rows. That's what indexes are for.

The most you can do is pay attention to the design of the tables, indexing strategy, and throw enough hardware at the solution.

If there was a silver bullet that anyone could answer in a paragraph or two here that applied universally (since you didn't give any insight to your table structure), don't you think it would already be built into MySQL?

The good news is that you will probably find that for most searches MySQL will do the job just fine even on massive databases.

Comment: Indexes will work but won't work since the time it would take to index a database of this size would be a very long time.

Comment: It might, but that's the tradeoff for search performance. Let's take this out of the computer world to demonstrate how the question is nonsensical. How could you find all instances of a word in a book more quickly than reading the book?

Comment: that is why you dont rebuild the index very often..

Comment: @NoahR: Building an index is slow, if it's new. However, when you do a search for the second time, it already paid for itself...

Comment: You'd obviously take pictures of each page and use a image to text algorithm to convert those images to text. Then you would do a simple text search using a text editor. That question is just silly.

Comment: Now. Assume that taking pictures of every page is a slow process (it is). How would you do the same thing without taking any pictures? That is exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @Cassy Would the index be faster if I created it via to the MySQL console rather than the PHPmyAdmin?

Comment: Answering your question to Cassy. No. It would not. MySQL ALWAYS creates the index. The UI you use to tell it to do the work doesn't matter.

Comment: That's relative to the amount of pages the book has and how fast you can take those pictures ;). In comparison to the time it would take to type those pages out digitally it's much faster.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. It is a metaphor. Of course you would use a computer. But you are trying to say how can I make the computer search the data without the computer reading all the data at least once (creating an index)? It is as silly as searching a book for a word without looking at all of it (computer or human).